How to access the data via context menu in uplot-vue graph
I have a simple graph with data plotted from 5 different features showing their speed over time. When a user right clicks on data on the graph, I display a context menu with a few options, one of them being a simple "Get Info" option where I'd like to display a dialog containing more detailed data about the feature they clicked on.
I'm having a hard time getting to the data within the graph. So far I have tried using the uplot cursor.idxs to get the location of the click from this example with no success:
https://jsfiddle.net/w07t8q4g/
I am not sure how to accomplish this. Can anyone help? Thanks so much!
This is my component code so far:
<template>
<div @contextmenu.prevent="showContextMenu($event)">
  <ContextMenu
      v-model="showMenu"
      :x="menuX"
      :y="menuY"
      :actions="contextMenuActions"
      @action-clicked="handleMenuAction"
    />
      <v-main class="pa-0">
        <v-container fluid >
              <v-card >
                <div id="uplot-Container" style="min-height: 350px; max-height: 400px;">
                <UplotVue ref="timelineContainer" :options="options" :data="plotData" :key="graphKey" />
              </div>
              </v-card>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {onMounted, onUpdated, ref, watch} from 'vue'
import "uplot/dist/uPlot.min.css";

import UplotVue from 'uplot-vue';
import ContextMenu from '@/components/ContextMenu.vue';
import {useState} from "@/store/State"
const stateStore = useStateStore()

import {storeToRefs} from 'pinia'

const graphKey = ref(0)
const timelineContainer = ref(null)
const height = ref(null)
const width = ref(null)

const showMenu = ref(false)
const menuX = ref(0)
const menuY = ref(0)

const contextMenuActions = ref([
  { label: 'Get Info', action: 'getInfo', icon: 'mdi-information-box-outline', disabled: false },
  { label: 'Sync', action: 'sync', icon: 'mdi-autorenew', disabled: false },
]);

const plotData = stateStore.plotData

const showContextMenu = (event) => {
  //the context menu adds pixels to the x and y to show it offset, so get the correct pixel that was actually right clicked to find feature
  event.preventDefault()

  //this is the pixel location for the menu based on where the user right clicked and what gets passed to the contextMenu component for placement on screen.
  menuX.value = event.clientX
  menuY.value = event.clientY
  showMenu.value = true
}

function handleMenuAction(action){
  console.log(action)
  console.log('x: '+menuX.value + ' ' +'y: '+menuY.value)`enter code here`
  if (action === 'getInfo') {
    //Get the feature's data at the location of the click

//THIS DOESN'T WORK - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'idxs')
    const [xIdx, yIdx] = timelineContainer.value.cursor.idxs

    const xVal = timelineContainer.value.data[0][xIdx]
    const yVal = timelineContainer.value.data[1][yIdx]
    const xPos = timelineContainer.value.valToPos(xVal, 'x');
    const yPos = timelineContainer.value.valToPos(yVal, 'y');
    let popup = document.createElement("div");
    popup.classList.add("popup");
    popup.textContent = yVal;
    popup.style.left = xPos + "px";
    popup.style.top = yPos + "px";

    timelineContainer.value.over.appendChild(popup);
  }
}

const options = ref({
  Title: "Plotted Data",
    drawOrder: ["series", "axes"],
    axes: [
      {
        side:0,
        stroke: "white",
        ticks: {
          stroke: "#808080"
        },
        grid: {
          stroke: "rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.5)"
        }
      },
      {
        stroke: "white",
        ticks: {
          stroke: "#808080"
        },
        grid: {
          stroke: "rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.5)"
        },
        
      }
    ],
    series: [
      {
        label: 'Timstamp'
      },
      {
        label: 'CM',
        stroke: "red",
        width: 4
      },
      {
        label: "NC",
        stroke: "green",
        width: 4
      },
      {
        label: "OE",
        stroke: "blue",
        width: 4
      },
      {
        label: "SB",
        stroke: "orange",
        width: 4
      },
      {
        label: "ST",
        stroke: "yellow",
        width: 4
      },
    ],
    scales: { x: { time: true } },
  },)



onUpdated(() => {
  graphKey.value++
  const element = document.getElementById('uplot-Container')
  const positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect()
  const height = positionInfo.height
  const width = positionInfo.width
 
  options.value = {
    ...options.value,
    height: height - 50,
    width: width - 30
  }
})

onMounted(() => {
 console.log(plotData.value)
})

This is what the graph looks like with the 5 different features and its data over time

